# Connecting to MariaDB Server on Termux Android

Tags: android, mysql, mariadb, termux

I'm working on launching a NodeJS project directly on a local database on an Android Device and for this I use Termux and MariaDB Server.

It perfectly works after using the commands

```
mysqld &
```

and

```
node mynodefile.js
```

on Termux. But I would like to avoid the "mysqld &" command and launch the MariaDB Server in another way. So I downloaded the MariaDB Server App for Android. But even if I launch the server with it, Termux doesn't even detect the new process and I can't access to mysql. It gives me the following error:

```
$ mysql -u root -p -h127.0.0.1
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/var/lib/mysqld.sock' (111)
```

It seems that the server is still off... How can I resolve my problem?

Comment: Try `-h localhost` or `-h ::1`

Answer (score 4):

try

```
$mysql_install_db

$mysqld
```

then

```
$mysql -u root -p
```

Answer (score 1):

I finally avoided it by just modifying my source code to reach the MariaDB Server. And I connected my mobile app to my NodeJS project with Cordova. I don't need Termux anymore.

Answer (score 1):

Solution for termux:

1. Run `mysqld_safe`
2. Open new session
3. Run `mysql -u $(whoami)`
4. Change privilages to root, change password to root and flush changes (tutor in mysql doc), `quit;`
5. Run `mysql -u root -p`

Answer (score 1):

**Step 1** : *pip install mysql-connector-python*
Copy the path where it is installed

Ex: ***/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages***

**Step 2** : paste the copied path (/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages)

Stpe 3 : Create a file(Ex: nano file1.py)
In the file1

```
import mysql.connector as sql
conn=sql.connect(host='localhost',user='root',password ='', database ='ccms')
if conn.is_connected():
  print("successfully connected")
```

And so on! Normal procedure as you do in computer or you can be quided further from the below link for creating databases, adding tables, modifying,etc.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Before run `mysql_install_db` try create `my.cnf.d` folder in `/data/data/com.termux.files/usr/etc`. Work for me.

```
$ cd /data/data/com.termux.files/usr/etc
$ mkdir my.cnf.d
$ mysql_install_db
$ mysqld_safe -u root &
$ mysql -u root
```

Source:
https://parzibyte.me/blog/2018/11/12/instalar-mysql-mariadb-en-android-con-termux/

Answer (score 0):

I am facing like your problem.But not have in Stackoverflow to solve this problem.
So I tried to solve this problem by asking issue in termux GitHub.But I solved from this.
https://github.com/termux/termux-packages/issues/4540
If u are the starter keep following.
sudo apt update && apt upgrade -y
sudo apt install mariadb

And open mariadb
mysqld_safe -u root &
If not working try
mysql
(cuz you are not root user,I mean not in real linux)
When you close termux app and next time you try you get like this problem.
mysql
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/tmp/mysqld.sock' (2)

So clear this by following.
sudo clear

cd '/data/data/com.termux/files/usr' ; /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/bin/mysqld_safe --datadir='/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/var/lib/mysql'

and past it.Above command.And open new session.
Type
sudo mysql
You can make database and you will see welcome of mariadb.
If you get some connection problem.Try below.
When you opened mariadb.
Let type

sudo CREATE USER 'root' IDENTIFIED BY 'p@ssw9rd';
p@ssw9rd is password and root is default username.
You can change p@ssw9rd.

sudo GRANT ALL ON DATABASE_NAME.* TO root@localhost IDENTIFIED BY 'p@ssw9rd';

At database_name,type your db Name.
This is al problem and never have hard more than this.

Answer (score 0):

## Installation

```
pkg update & pkg upgrade
pkg install mariadb
```

## Run mariadb daemon

```
mysqld
```

Or use this

```
mysqld_safe
```

## Create new user and password

```
mysql
use mysql;
set password for 'new_user'@'localhost' = password('YOUR_ROOT_PASSWORD_HERE');
flush privileges;
quit;
```

## Login with new user

```
mysql -u new_user -p
```

And then input your password.

**Note! Every time you use mysql in termux, the mariadb daemon must be activated first**